# Azure App Service - An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException - Wcf

Tags: asp.net, azure, wcf, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

Hi I have deployed wcf service in UAT environment as azure App service. and client calling getting below error -

The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action '/GetExams' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.

On SIT environment and local it works with same configuration. what could be the issue? help appreciated!

Comment: If ARR Affinity enabled, that is a client is tied to a specific web worker resulting in unequal distribution of traffic across various worker instances.
So, to avoid the unequal distribution of traffic & improve performance we need to the client to be tied to a worker for them to work e.g. Applications using In-Process session. If this is not the case, disable ARR Affinity to achieve a more even load distribution and see if it helps.

Comment: Kindly let us know if the above works or you need further assistance. similar issues where fixed by disabling ARR Affinity; see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, you can try to increase the [receiveTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.receivetimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) and [inactivityTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.reliablesession.inactivitytimeout?view=netframework-4.8) properties.

Answer (score 0):

If ARR Affinity enabled, that is a client is tied to a specific web worker resulting in unequal distribution of traffic across various worker instances. So, to avoid the unequal distribution of traffic & improve performance we need to the client to be tied to a worker for them to work e.g. Applications using In-Process session. If this is not the case, disable ARR Affinity to achieve a more even load distribution and see if it helps.